# Make WFFM field required based on the value of another field

Tags: wffm

I am looking for a way to get a WFFM field to be required only if another field has a certain value. If there is a way to make a WFFM field required on the fly through Javascript, that would work fine, but I don't know of a way. Additionally, while the rules engine allows me to select my condition (other field matches value), there is no rule to make the field required.

One of my thoughts was to create a custom rule then, to serve as the action, but the problem I'm running into there is, how would I make a WFFM field required on the fly in C#? Researched online and didn't find anything.

I've found a [resource](https://soyouwannasitecore.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/sitecore-wffm-required-if-outlined/) that matched my exact scenario:

- If contact method selected is Phone, make the Phone field required
- If contact method selected is Email, make the Email field required

... but I don't understand it. I don't understand which part of the code is actually making the Contact Preference field required. Additionally, the code has some problems and I can't get it to build.

I am using Sitecore 8.0 with WFFM (unknown version).

Comment: Add version of Sitecore that you use. Can you maybe use similar approach of showing/hiding fields on WFFM form -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919088/webforms-for-marketers-form-fields-conditional-visibility-dynamically? For your case you would not show or hide but set requirement of another field. I don't have Sitecore below 9 version installed so I cannot check. If there is no rule like that then create one :)

Comment: The link does not apply because there is no Action in the rules editor for my field that allows me to make another field required. Additionally I do not see "Hide element" action. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/0KLTQ9D.png. Can you give more information on *how I could create a rule that would make a field required?*

Comment: Also, creating a rule for my requirement means it would be processed server side (once on page load) but I need to make a field required in response to a dropdown selection, so creating a rule would not work.. unless I could make it triggered via Javascript, which I am not sure how to do.

Comment: How about having two similar fields on the form – `Field1` already configured with all the valid mandatory validations but HIDDEN on Page Load and `Field2` without any validations & visible. Then write custom JavaScript to show/hide the mandate/non-mandate fields based on the values in your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

How about having two fields on the form – `Field1` already configured with all the valid mandatory validations but **Hidden** on Page Load and `Field2` without any validations but **Visible**. Then:

**Approach 1:**

Write custom JavaScript to show/hide the mandate/non-mandate fields based on the values in your requirements.

**Approach 2:**

Please have a look at the solution described Sitecore Documentation Portal: [Show or hide a form field depending on other field value](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/80/working_with_fields_actions_and_validations/fields/show_or_hide_form_fields_depending_on_other_field_values#_Add_a_script)s.